Cannot get a correct quantum count for a sudoku example
I've implemented a quantum counting algorithm for a sudoku example by following
the amplitude estimation algorithm introduced in Mosca's textbook (An Introduction to Quantum Computing, page#172):

However, when I ran my code I got an incorrect counting 13, while the right count is 2 (this sudoku has 2 answers).
I've verified the grover's operator(oracle+diffuser) gives a right answer for the sudoku, thus I believe something should be wrong with other parts of the circuit other than Grover's operator itself but don't now where.
I would appreciate any hints from you on my implementation. I've attached a diagram of my circuit.


The answer was explained here. I needed to output N - M as the number of solutions instead of just M. This fix's given a right answer.
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram, plot_bloch_multivector, plot_distribution
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from numpy import pi
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate, XGate, RZGate, SGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, SamplerV2 as Sampler

service = QiskitRuntimeService()


# In[2]:


def diffuser(nqubits):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    circ = QuantumCircuit(nqubits)
    # Apply transformation |s> -> |00..0> (H-gates)
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
        circ.h(qubit)
    # Apply transformation |00..0> -> |11..1> (X-gates)
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
        circ.x(qubit)
    # Do multi-controlled-Z gate
    circ.h(nqubits-1)
    
    circ.append(XGate().control(nqubits-1), list(range(nqubits))) 
    
    circ.h(nqubits-1)
    # Apply transformation |11..1> -> |00..0>
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
        circ.x(qubit)
    # Apply transformation |00..0> -> |s>
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
        circ.h(qubit)
    # We will return the diffuser as a gate
    U_s = circ.to_gate()
    U_s.name = "U_0"
    return U_s


# In[3]:


# apply inverse phase shift rotation gates in recursive 
def inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    # get theta index for rotation
    l = range(2, m-n+2)
    revl = list(l)[::-1]

    control_idx = 0
    n-=1
        
    for k in revl:
        circuit.cp(-pi/2**(k-1), control_idx, m-n-1)
        control_idx+=1
    circuit.h(m-n-1)
    return inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m)


# In[4]:


# apply swap gates
def qft_swap(circuit, n):
    # num of times of swap
    swap_num = (int)(n/2)
    m = n-1
    for i in range(swap_num):
        circuit.swap(i, m)
        m -= 1 


# In[5]:


# apply inverse qft transform
def inv_qft(circuit, n, m):
    qft_swap(circuit, n)
    inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m)


# In[6]:


# apply phase shift rotation gates in recursive 
def qft_rotation(circuit, n):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    n-=1
    circuit.h(n)
    control_idx = n-1
    for k in range(2, n+2):
        circuit.cp(pi/2**(k-1), control_idx, n)
        control_idx-=1
    return qft_rotation(circuit, n)


# In[7]:


# apply swap gates
def qft_swap(circuit, n):
    # num of times of swap
    swap_num = (int)(n/2)
    m = n-1
    for i in range(swap_num):
        circuit.swap(i, m)
        m -= 1 


# In[8]:


# apply qft transform
def qft(circuit, n):
    qft_rotation(circuit, n)
    qft_swap(circuit, n)


# In[9]:


# problem1 
# sudoku
# ---------
# |V0 | V1|
# |-------|
# |V2 | V3|
# ---------


# In[10]:


clause_list = [[0,1], [2,3], [0,2], [1,3]]


# In[11]:


def XOR(qc, a, b, output):
    qc.cx(a, output)
    qc.cx(b, output)


# In[12]:


nqubits = len(clause_list)
tqubits = nqubits + 1


# In[13]:


# prepare registers
count_qubits = QuantumRegister(tqubits, name='count')
var_qubits = QuantumRegister(nqubits, name='v')
clause_qubits = QuantumRegister(nqubits, name='c')
output_qubit = QuantumRegister(1, name='out')
meas = ClassicalRegister(tqubits, name="meas")
qc = QuantumCircuit(count_qubits, var_qubits, clause_qubits, output_qubit, meas)
#qc.draw()


# In[14]:


# apply QFT/hadamard gate
#qc.h(count_qubits)
qft(qc, tqubits)
qc.h(var_qubits)

#qc.barrier()
#qc.draw()


# In[15]:


def sudoku_oracle(nqubits):
    var_qubits = QuantumRegister(nqubits)
    clause_qubits = QuantumRegister(nqubits)
    output_qubit = QuantumRegister(1)
    circ = QuantumCircuit(var_qubits, clause_qubits, output_qubit)    
    # Compute clauses
    i = 0
    #compute clauses
    for clause in clause_list:
        XOR(circ, var_qubits[clause[0]], var_qubits[clause[1]], clause_qubits[i])
        i += 1
    # inverse the output qubit if all the control bits are 1.
    circ.append(XGate().control(nqubits), list(clause_qubits)+[output_qubit])
    circ.z(output_qubit)
    circ.append(XGate().control(nqubits), list(clause_qubits)+[output_qubit])
    
    #uncompute clauses
    i = 0
    for clause in clause_list[::-1]:
        XOR(circ, var_qubits[clause[1]], var_qubits[clause[0]], clause_qubits[nqubits-1-i])
        i += 1
    U_f = circ.to_gate()
    U_f.label = "U_f"
    return U_f


# In[16]:


def get_grover_op(niter, nqubits):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    var_qubits = QuantumRegister(nqubits)
    clause_qubits = QuantumRegister(nqubits)
    output_qubit = QuantumRegister(1)
    q = QuantumCircuit(var_qubits, clause_qubits, output_qubit)
    for i in range(niter):
        q.append(sudoku_oracle(nqubits), list(var_qubits)+list(clause_qubits)+[output_qubit])
        q.append(diffuser(nqubits), list(var_qubits))
    U_g = q.to_gate()
    U_g.label = f"Grover$^{niter}$"
    return U_g


# In[17]:


repetitions = 1
for counting_qubit in range(tqubits):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    gop = get_grover_op(repetitions, nqubits)
    circ_grover_iter = gop.control()
    qc.append(circ_grover_iter, [count_qubits[counting_qubit]]+list(var_qubits)+list(clause_qubits)+[output_qubit])
    repetitions *= 2


# In[18]:


# Apply inverse QFT
inv_qft(qc, tqubits, tqubits)
for i in range(tqubits):
   qc.measure(count_qubits[i], meas[i])
qc.draw("mpl",plot_barriers = False,fold=-1)


# In[19]:


backend = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=0)
shots = 1024

isa_qc = pm.run(qc)
sampler = Sampler(backend)
result = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots).result()

pub_result = result[0]
counts = pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()

plot_distribution(counts, title="phase estimation")


# In[20]:


measured_str = max(counts, key=counts.get)
measured_int = int(measured_str, 2)
print("Register Output = %i" % measured_int)


# In[21]:


theta = pi * measured_int/(2**tqubits)
print("theta = %f" % theta)


# In[22]:


N = 2**nqubits
print("N = %i" % N)
M = N * (math.sin(theta)**2)
print("num of solutions : %f " % (N-M))


# In[ ]:

num of solutions : 2.343146
